# The plant functions in three different shifts as given below (timings are in IST timezone) in any date Make it in python program

Tags: python, time, shift

[image]

I want make a 3 shift of timing given below

Comment: Could you provide some more info?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EO8M88O9OMezoxnOTKS0DQzK77vDYJOp?usp=sharing